# Order of Acidic strength: Phosphorus oxoacids

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I was asked to compare the acidic strength of the following phosphorus oxoacids,

> [image]

I thought the order (of strength) would be $\ce{H3PO4 > H3PO3 > H3PO2}$, because they have three, two and one ionizable $\ce{O-H}$ bonds (that furnish protons / $\ce{H^+}$ ions).

However, looking up the $\pu{pK_a}$ values on the respective Wikipedia pages of each of those acids, suggests the exact *opposite* order of acidic strength:
$\ce{H3PO2 > H3PO3 > H3PO4}$. Apparently the acid with *one* $\ce{O-H}$ bond is a far stronger than the acid with *three* $\ce{O-H}$ bonds!

This is horribly counter-intuitive :-(

So, **why** is the correct order of acidic strength  $\ce{H3PO2 > H3PO3 > H3PO4}$, and not the other way around as I believed? What was wrong with my analysisi ( acidity in oxoacids $\propto$ number of $\ce{O-H}$ bonds)?

Comment: (+1) It's possible that this question should be separated into two parts. The $\pu{p}K_\pu{a}$ values are measured in water where tautomerisation is significant. To directly compare the acidities of the depicted compounds we should move into the gas phase, and compare the $\Delta G_\pu{r}^\circ$ values of deprotonation. Sadly, I only found data for $\ce{H3PO4}$ as shown in OP, written as  $\Delta_\pu{r} G^\circ = 1351\ \pu{kJ mol^{-1}}$, doi: [10.1063/1.473465](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.473465). Further information might be available from computational studies.

Comment: It was asked maybe half a dozen times already, check out the site before asking.

Comment: There was also https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38034/why-is-h3po2-more-acidic-than-h3po4 and terrible https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65146/why-is-phosphorous-acid-more-acidic-than-phosphoric-acid

Comment: @Mith Ah, I see :-(

Comment: There was a better duplicate I think. If I find it mod can add second one. It's recurring question, because it's defying common "rules".

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/77309/can-the-effect-of-resonance-on-acidity-be-generalised needs duping probably

Comment: @Mith Gee, thanks ;-) But the answer to the duplicate you proposed first seems less controversial than the answer to *this* post. I'm not sure myself, so I'd like the Mods (or anyone with a sound knowledge of the matter) to compare the answers (with existing literature). Let the post with the better answer be the "original" O:)

Comment: It's better then this one but not fully correct I think; there was still better one IIRC

Answer (score 3):

Acidic strength of the acids is determined on the relative tendency to donate one proton.

The source where you have seen then $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value has considered the tendency of *first* deprotonation of the acids ($\ce{H3PO2}$ deprotonates once, $\ce{H3PO3}$ can deprotonate twice and $\ce{H3PO4}$ can deprotonate thrice).

The double bonded oxygen has negative inductive effect (*-I*). And this electron withdrawing effect is experienced by one $\ce{H}$ of the one $\ce{-OH}$ group in $\ce{H3PO2}$. Hence it has greatest acidic strength.

Similarly, the *-I* effect of $\ce{O}$ is experienced by two $\ce{H}$ of the two $\ce{-OH}$ groups in $\ce{H3PO3}$, hence electron withdrawing effect is reduced because it is getting distributed between two groups. Hence, it has lesser acidic strength. Similarly, in $\ce{H3PO4}$, it is distributed between 3 groups and so the acidic strength is least.

Thus the acidic strength, is:
$$\ce{H3PO2 > H3PO3 > H3PO4}$$
(I hope it's clear.)

Comment: I'm not convinced by this explanation. Do you have a source?

Comment: @orthocresol I have read this explanation for the oxyacids of P in my textbooks. And whether you are convinced or not, it's a fact. But, if you have any other considerations and explanations, feel free to comment and answer this question.

Comment: I second what @ortho said. It would be helpful if you could list a source that mentions this. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @paracetamol Actually, I studied this in my textbooks and also my teacher told this while studying various applications of inductive effect, Mesomeric effect, hyperconjugation, etc. This is a basic concept. But, I think I have the name of a popular book in which I read it.... I'm checking out in google books. I'll upload a screenshot, if possible, shortly.

Comment: Why can't this explanation be applied to the oxyacids of sulfur, namely sulfuric acid and sulfurous acid?

Comment: @TanYongBoon see... In sulphuric acid there are two double bonded O and in sulphurous acid there is one double bonded O with the central atom. But, there are same number of -OH groups in both. So, in H2SO4, the negative inductive effect is much more due to two double bonded O and hence it is more acidic. You can practically explain several oxyacids by this method. For example take..HOCl, HClO2, HClO3 and HClO4. This can also be explained way. Just considering the number of double bonded O and -OH groups present.

Comment: @paracetamol And while answering, we have some knowledge from which we answer and it is not always possible to cite a source. But if possible, if usually do that. This is based on a basic concept of chemistry. Suppose, you are said to compare some carbocation stability. So will you cite a source?

Comment: Please do upvote my comments if you really agree with me.

Comment: While your answer seems convincing to me (I'm not a chemist though), it's always appreciated if a source is included when talking about not-so-familiar cases. As for carbocation stability, I would cite [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbocation#Structure_and_properties)  (which cites other articles) or some standard Org. Chem textbook :-)

Comment: This answer makes no sense, it's just **not** working like this and this question **can't** be answered on basis of inductive/mesomeric effects.

Comment: I’m not convinced because inductive effects simply aren’t “shared”. As the writer of an answer, the burden of proof lies on **you**. I can claim that the Sun orbits around the Earth and I’m sure you would agree that the responsibility for proving it would be entirely mine.

Comment: @orthocresol See....I have read this as an explanation and hence I wrote this here. Even you can google it and you can find that in many sites such as Quora, libretexts, quantumstudy, etc.

Comment: Also Pauling’s rules are based on resonance not inductive effects. Inductive effects won’t explain a pKa difference of ~5 between HClO3 and HClO4

Comment: @orthocresol see... I'm not a chemist and not a researcher..... I'm a student and since during my chemistry course I studied this I wrote it here.

Comment: @orthocresol I know that they are not trustworthy sources. for that reason only I did never cite those. But, this concept regarding acidic strength of oxidised of phosphorus is a common and basic concept. I studied this while studying inductive effect in my textbooks.

Comment: This is wrong, so very wrong. Wherever you got this information from: throw it away, it's wrong. And if that is wrong, I wouldn't trust anything else from that source either.